# What is the value of a bet that pays zero if Albert loses overall and pays his winnings if he wins?

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Question: Albert and Bob are playing a coin flipping game. If the coin comes up heads, Albert wins $\$1$; if it comes up tails, Bob wins $\$1$. The coin is biased so that the probability of heads is $0.7$. Albert and Bob will play $4$ games. What is the value of a bet that pays zero if Albert loses overall and pays his winnings if he wins? Give your answer to two decimal places.

I was asked this interview question during interview.

I am not able to understand what they are asking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The value of a bet is not a fixed amount but a return rate of interest on the investment.

The odds to win overall for heads are 65.17%
Those come out of the odds of loosing once or winning all:
$4\cdot (0.3)\cdot (0.7)^3 +(0.7)^4=0.6517$

Therefore a bet against overall win on heads has 100%-65.17%=34.83% odds to win.

I guess that to a normalized bet representing 100%, the bet against overall winning for heads will pay 100/65.17 x 34.83 = 53.44%

Answer (score 1):

The outcome of the "bet" referred to isn't incompletely specified, because:

- You're not told explicitly how much Albert loses if the coin comes up tails.  *Presumably*, the two players are betting against each other, and so Albert would lose $\$1$ whenever the coin comes up tails.
- Even if this presumption is correct, there would still be a positive probability $\ 6\cdot0.7^2\cdot0.3^2\ $ that Albert breaks even, and you're not told what the bet will pay if that happens. Again, you might reasonably *presume* that the bet would pay zero also in the cases when Albert breaks even.

If the above two presumptions are correct then the bet will pay $\$4$ with probability $0.7^4$ (when four heads come up), $\$2$ with probability $4\cdot0.7^3\cdot0.3 \hspace{1pt} $ (when three heads come up)$\hspace{-1pt}\,^1$, and zero otherwise, so the expected return in dollars would be
\begin{align}
4\cdot0.7^4 + 8\cdot0.7^3\cdot0.3&= 1.7836\\
&\approx 1.78\ \text{ (to two decimal places),}
\end{align}
which I would presume is what your interviewers meant by the "value" of the "bet".

$\hspace{-1pt}\,^1$ Thanks to [KKKoo0](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/596432/kkkoo0) in the comments below for a correction to this quantity.

Comment: isnt the probability of winning $2   \begin{align} C(4,3) * 0.7^3 * 0.3 \end{align}, i.e, \begin{align}  4*0.7^3 * 0.3 \end{align}

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

assume

- Albert wins $4 if there are 4 heads, the probability is \begin{align} 0.7^4 \end{align}
- Albert wins $2 if there are 3 heads, the probability is \begin{align} C(4,3)*0.7^3 * 0.3 \end{align}
- Albert wins $0 if there are 2 heads, the probability is \begin{align} C(4,2)*0.7^2 * 0.3^2 \end{align}
- Albert wins $0 if there are 1 heads as Albert loses overall, the probability is \begin{align} C(4,1)*0.7 * 0.3^3 \end{align}
- Albert wins $0 if there are 0 heads as Albert loses overall, the probability is \begin{align} 0.3^4 \end{align}

So overall, the value of the game is

\begin{align} $4*0.7^4 +   $2* C(4,3)*0.7^2 * 0.3^2 = 1.78 \end{align}